# Catch only object reflection alpha with glossy material

Tags: shaders, transparency

I have an object in a plane with glossy material. I wanted to do a render but only !

- the object itself
- the reflection of the object
- the shadow of the object
- the plane in full transparency (100% transparent <=> alpha 0).

I have tried everything, also render layer without success.
Glass Shader also didn't work for me (even with the transparent glass checked in film).
Below is an example with a sphere : I want to render ONLY the sphere, his reflection and all the rest with alpha transparency !

[image: Image with grey background]

What I want :
[image: What I want]

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Like [THIS](https://imgur.com/a/DAqBjsp) or like [THIS](https://imgur.com/a/ccc76Es) ? The Original is [THIS ONE](https://imgur.com/a/TEOFF6r)

Comment: At first it sounds like only the reflection, but then it sounds like object + reflection with no ground plane or shadows?  Please [edit] your post with a little more clarity on what you want the result to be.  A crude mock-up often helps.

Comment: Hello, excuse me to not having been clear, in fact based on @Emir comment's last link (https://imgur.com/a/TEOFF6r), I want this BUT the plane needs to be totally transparent. The goal is to have this object integrated ahead of another background texture so I just want the object+shadow+reflection BUT NOT the color of the plane(which must be total transparency). Like a shadow + reflection catcher object property on the plane. Hope this can be more clear :)